# PowerShell 'q' does not break a 'more' process

Tags: powershell, console

When I do something like `man gci -detailed`, I get the full help file piped to `more` and I can scroll through page by page. I have always known that pressing `q` should break this operation back to a prompt. On some systems this works (pressing `q` breaks the `more` operation). On other systems (with identical PowerShell setups, same modules, profile etc), this fails completely, `q` does nothing(!). This also happens even if I start `powershell.exe -noProfile`.

Does anyone have some insight on what could be causing this? I thought it could be a PSReadLine issue, but I've tried removing and restarting that also but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does tapping Q-key while running `man gci -detailed | more.com` fail as well?

Comment: That also fails on affected systems. `-detailed` also just invokes `more` (which is a PowerShell function, not `more.com` from DOS):

`cat function:\more`

`param([string[]]$paths)
$OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::OutputEncoding
if($paths) {
    foreach ($file in $paths)
    {
        Get-Content $file | more.com
    }
} else { $input | more.com }`


I see that `help` is also a function. `cat function:\help`. But none of these functions have been altered on the affected systems, so I don't see why `q` fails to work just on some systems.

Comment: On my PC, `man` calls `Get-Help @PSBoundParameters | more`; but since `more` is not clarified, it could be any extension defined by %PATHEXT% (eg, .COM, .EXE, .BAT, .CMD, .VBS, .VBE, .JS, .JSE, .WSF, .WSH, .MSC) and depending upon %PATH%, it could be finding an alternate version of `more` besides the built-in OS `C:\Windows\system32\more.com`.  That said, see if `Get-Help gci -detailed | C:\Windows\system32\more.com` produces the same result.  If not, use %PATH% and %PATHEXT% to locate the nefarious `more` on affected systems.  HTH.

Comment: I see that `cat function:\man` and `cat function:\help` are identical and the important lines are:

`#Set the outputencoding to Console::OutputEncoding. More.com doesn't work well with Unicode. ; $outputEncoding=[System.Console]::OutputEncoding ; 
Get-Help @PSBoundParameters | more`
Could my issue have something to do with some odd Unicode setting, or yes, something to do with PowerShell `more` vs `more.com`. I will look into a bit further thanks. Yes, I will hunt for alternative `more` executables (I think it's not that, but let's see...).

Comment: From DOS: `where more` => `C:\Windows\System32\more.com`. So it looks like I can only be using the PowerShell `more` function or DOS `more.com`. But from PowerShell, that will default to the `more` PowerShell function.

Comment: Weirdly, when I do `get-help gci | more` or `get-help gci | more.com` (in a small screen so that it forces to do multiple pages), `q` works(!). Completely stumped why this isn't working for `man gci -detailed` (when it works fine on other systems).

Comment: It should indeed (unless ISE) be more.com that's being called, just like the function output you pasted shows. You could try hardcoding the path of more.com and see what kinda result you get. For instance, try running this in your console `$function:more = @'
param([string[]]$paths)
$OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::OutputEncoding
if($paths) {
    foreach ($file in $paths)
    {
        Get-Content $file | C:\Windows\System32\more.com
    }
} else { $input | C:\Windows\System32\more.com }
'@`

Comment: Ah yes, ultimately it's using `more.com` via the `more` function, good point. ok, I tried hard-coding it as you suggest by overwriting the `more` function and it still doesn't work. `q` just acts like hitting the space bar and pages forward one screen.